# Concurrent read-modify-write in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to do in SQL:

- step 1: read data from tables A, B, C
- step 2: do some calculations
- write back data to tables A, B, C

But this must be concurrent proof, meaning that once step 1 is done, every other instance needs to wait for step 1 until step 3 is finished since it changes the data to do the calculations. Here is a simplified example (I´ve left out some declarations and used hard coded values):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddOrder AS BEGIN
    -- Step 1: read (every other call to AddOrder should wait here until this procedure has finished
    SELECT @TotalOrderAmount = sum(Amount) FROM Orders WHERE CustomerID = 5

    -- Step 2: modify
    SELECT @DiscountPct = CASE WHEN @TotalOrderAmount > 1000.00 THEN 0.10 ELSE 0.00 END
    SELECT @Amount = 9.99 * (1 - @DiscountPct)

    -- Step 3: write
    INSERT INTO Orders(CustomerID, Amount) VALUES (5, @Amount)
END
```

The first thing in my mind was of course use a transaction with a raised isolation level:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATBLE READ
BEGIN TRAN
    -- Step 1
    -- Step 2
    -- Step 3
COMMIT TRAN
```

But this won't solve anything. Assume that 2 connections execute the procedure at exactly the same time. Step 1 will place and hold a shared_read lock and both connections will go trough step one which is already wrong. But it gets worse, since there are 2 locks on the table that will be updated in step 3, there will be a deadlock.

I don't want to group everything into a single statement (if this would solve anything) because my real situation is of course more complex than the example.

I also would like to use the range locking of a modern SQL Server rather than locking the entire table, so that only the rows for that CustomerID will be locked.
And finally, i don't won´t optimistic locking, so both calls should always succeed.

Does anyone has a simple solution for this problem?

UPDATE:

At first, it seems that using a table hint UPDLOCK would solve the issue. For example:

```
    BEGIN TRAN
        -- Step 1: read or wait until other instance has finished
        SELECT @TotalOrderAmount = sum(Amount) FROM Orders with (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK) WHERE CustomerID = 5

        -- Step 2: modify
        SELECT @DiscountPct = CASE WHEN @TotalOrderAmount > 1000.00 THEN 0.10 ELSE 0.00 END
        SELECT @Amount = 9.99 * (1 - @DiscountPct)

        -- Step 3: write
        INSERT INTO Orders(CustomerID, Amount) VALUES (5, @Amount)
    COMMIT TRAN
```

The great benefit is that only the order rows for CustomerID = 5 will be locked so most of the calls won't even wait at all since they are used with different customers.

But this approach still leaves one major shortcoming: for new customers it won't work at all, since there are no rows yet to lock. So 2 concurrent calls with the same new CustomerID (that has no orders yet) won't wait for each other.

So in addition to UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK i would need something like

- if the range exist, do a ROWLOCK
- if the range doesn't exist, do a TABLOCK (or something like a 'new row lock')

Something like

```
BEGIN TRAN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE CustomerID = 5)
        SELECT @TotalOrderAmount = sum(Amount) FROM Orders with (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK) WHERE CustomerID = 5
    ELSE
        SELECT @TotalOrderAmount = sum(Amount) FROM Orders with (UPDLOCK, TABLOCK) WHERE CustomerID = 5
```

But in 1 statement (because the IF EXISTS also needs to be concurrent proof). The TABLOCK also doesn't seems the best solution because when a new customer is selected, the existing customers (acquiring a ROWLOCK) are also waiting for the release of the TABLOCK. That's why I mention 'new row lock' above.

Comment: If you start by doing a fake update (such as Amount=Amount) on the row, then the other select will wait, depending on the isolation level.

Comment: How about a locking hint on table level, not on transaction? Take a look [**here**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213026(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: That's what SNAPSHOT isolation is for. You should rethink the statement though - it could be rewritten as a single `INSERT`. In general, `read-modify-write` is a *very strong smell*. There are always other ways to do the same thing

Comment: You could write a simple `INSERT .. SELECT` to insert the values you want. Why do you want to break this into multiple steps?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UPDLOCK` / `XLOCK` hint on the `SELECT` after starting a transaction.
 Something like this.

**Sample Table Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    OrderID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CustomerID INT NOT NULL,
    Amount NUMERIC(18,2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX IDX_Cutomer_Orders ON Orders(CustomerID) INCLUDE(Amount);

INSERT INTO Orders VALUES(1,123.25),(1,55),(2,8765900),(7,900);

INSERT INTO Orders VALUES(5,123.25),(5,8765900);
```

**PROCEDURE**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddOrder
@CustomerID INT
AS
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DECLARE @TotalOrderAmount NUMERIC(18,2),@Amount NUMERIC(18,2),@DiscountPct NUMERIC(4,2)
    -- Step 1: read (every other call to AddOrder should wait here until this procedure has finished
    SELECT @TotalOrderAmount = SUM(Amount) FROM Orders WITH (UPDLOCK ,ROWLOCK)
    WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID

    -- Step 2: modify
    SELECT @DiscountPct = CASE WHEN @TotalOrderAmount > 1000.00 THEN 0.10 ELSE 0.00 END
    SELECT @Amount = 9.99 * (1 - @DiscountPct)

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
    -- Step 3: write
    INSERT INTO Orders(CustomerID, Amount) VALUES (@CustomerID, @Amount)

    SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID

    COMMIT
END
```

Here, Simultaneous calls to `EXEC AddOrder 1` will wait for the initial one to `commit` / `rollback`.

Calls to `EXEC AddOrder 1` and `EXEC AddOrder 5` will work in parallel without blocking each other.

Comment: Holding locks is the *opposite* of concurrent proof. The  SNAPSHOT isolation mode was introduced to avoid exactly this problem

Comment: OP doesnt want to use snapshot isolation and he wants other transactions to wait

Comment: This is based on several incorrect assumptions, primarily that you can't combine INSERT and SELECT, or that records have to be processed one at a time. Anyway, delays only make matters worse by holding locks for longer. The OP's question could be answered by rewriting the statements as a simple `INSERT .. SELECT`.

Comment: You can't put everything into a single `insert into select` because as per OP - *"I don't want to group everything into a single statement (if this would solve anything) because my real situation is of course more complex than the example."*

Comment: @Panagiotis: Snapshot isolation isn't the solution. Sometimes it's just not enabled for a database (in a company), it's 'heavy' and it does use optimistic locking, which I don't want to use (every call needs to succeed). Also, 1 big query (combined insert/select) or several small doesn't make any difference. Even a single statement is wrapped implicitly into a transaction, which is READ_COMMITED by default and this also won't solve my issue (however, it will seem to work 99% of the times because you cannot test concurrency well without using a test delay between read and write)

Comment: @Bigjim you are making a lot of incorrect assumptions. That's not how INSERT/SELECT works - there is a huge difference as `INSERT/SELECT` will take the appropriate locks immediately. It's *not* a "complex" query either - in fact this is a very common statement. SNAPSHOT isolation is far, far lighter than locking when you need to modify multiple rows. If you have a lot of rows (thousands), it's far easier to use an ETL tool (eg SSIS) to process the data as a stream *and* use minimal logging.

Comment: If you want any subsequent process to read data including new changes and additions only after the insert / updates have been completed, how can Snapshot isolation help you in such a case? Also I am not sure what you mean by *"`INSERT/SELECT` will take the appropriate locks immediately"*. Insert / Select based on OP requirement will only work if you use locking hints like `WITH (UPDLOCK ,ROWLOCK)`. Otherwise 2 simultaneous calls to the same procedure can select the same data before inserting into the table. one doesn't wait to use for the data created by the other.

Comment: Anyway, it all depends on what the real requirement of *step 2* is which **we don't know** so hard to say if one approach is better than the other. we can only give out pointers to multiple ways of doing it

Comment: Oke, I was wrong about the single statement, that indeed should work. But it's still not an option since my real situation involves multiple tables and splitting logic into multiple statements will be also cleaner to read and debug. And for the snapshot option, I don't want to do unnecessary error and retry handling at a higher level.

Comment: @ughai: I really like your solution, it's indeed exact what I need. Only the rows for this customer will be locked so this won't impact the overall performance, assuming that it will be rare that the same customer places 2 orders at the same time, only in that specific case there will be a 'LOCK WAIT' during the calculation. But even when it occurs, everything will be handled correctly. My real situation is also about orders, but with many more checks to be done based on previous orders (like a credit limit, article limit, volume limit, ...)